# How to return items for 1 specific value and all other items with left join without doubling up in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Firstly, I'm sorry about the title of this post. I've found my issue quite difficult to put into words.

I have three tables:

```
item_crawls
---------------
id
item_id
units_sold
current_price


items
------------
id
item_title


favorites
-----------
id
product_id
user_id
```

The item_crawls table is a record of item movements ie. price changes, units sold over time. The item_crawls table relates to the items table in a one-to-many relationship.

The favorites table is for users to record their favorite items. The favorites table is linked to the items table in a one-to-many relationship. In the favorites table, a product_id / user_id combination is only allowed to occur once.

The items table is a base table for items. An item can only appear once in the items table.

I have this query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS distinct item_id as itemid , 
favorites.id as faveid , items.item_title as itemtitle, 
MAX(item_crawls.units_sold) as sold, 
ROUND(AVG(item_crawls.current_price),2) as aveprice from item_crawls 
INNER JOIN items on items.id = item_crawls.item_id left join favorites 
on favorites.product_id = items.id where item_crawls.units_sold > 1 
AND item_crawls.units_sold <= 500 
AND MATCH(items.item_title) AGAINST ('*cab*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
AND favorites.user_id = 1 group by item_crawls.item_id , faveid 
ORDER BY sold DESC limit 0,5
```

I'm trying to return all records for a particular search term, whilst at the same time returning the item's favorite status for a particular user. However, I also wish to return non-favorited items at the same time.

For example, if there are 10 items in the items table with item_title 'cable', and the user with id of 1 has favorited 2 of those items, I wish to return all 10 of the items, whilst also returning the favorites.id for the 2 favorited items. The remaining 8 non-favorited items should still be returned but with favorite.id being NULL.

The reason for this is when the items appear in the final view as a set of search results, I wish to have an icon appear next to each item indicating whether a user has favorited that item.

Problems:

1. If I specify favorites.user_id = 1 in the WHERE clause, it only returns items that user 1 has favorited, rather than returning all of the items.
2. If I don't specify favorites.user_id then the query doubles-up items which have been favorited by other users. So for example, if users 1, 2 and 3 have favorited an item, then the query will return the same item 3 times, along with single rows of the remaining non-favorited matches.

Is there a way to achieve this using a single query whilst overcoming the above 2 problems?

I don't want to have to perform an initial query for an item search, and then perform looped queries on the results to check whether a user has favorited the item, as that is very inefficient.

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the user_id check into the join criteria so it will not apply to the whole result set:

```
LEFT JOIN favorites ON favorites.product_id = items.id AND favorites.user_id = 1
```

To keep it in the WHERE clause would be:

```
(favorites.id IS NULL OR favorites.user_id = 1)
```

The faveid will be null if it is not favorited. You can use a case statement in the selectors to convert it to another value if that works better:

```
CASE WHEN favorites.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS favorite,
```

Also, looks like you need to group by itemtitle as well, and I doubt you need the distinct keyword if your relations are enforced.